I need this file to stringify a book, a chapter, and a verse but it stringifies multiple books at once
This file splits the text variable from book, chapter, and verses. It should ideally look like this:
[
  {
    "book": "PLACEHOLDER",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "chapter": 1,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "chapter": 1,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "book": "PLACEHOLDER",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "chapter": 1,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 2, chapter 1, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 2, chapter 1, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "chapter": 2,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 2, chapter 2, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 2, chapter 2, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

Instead, I got this, which duplicated the book but moved on to the next chapter:
[
  {
    "book": "PLACEHOLDER",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "chapter": 1,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "chapter": 1,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "book": "PLACEHOLDER",
    "chapters": [
      {
        "chapter": 2,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "chapter": 2,
        "verses": [
          {
            "verse": 1,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 1"
          },
          {
            "verse": 2,
            "text": "this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 2"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]

let text = `
this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 1.
this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 2.
*
this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 1.
this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 2.
#
this is book 2, chapter 1, verse 1.
this is book 2, chapter 1, verse 2.
*
this is book 2, chapter 2, verse 1.
this is book 2, chapter 2, verse 2.
`;

let volume = [];
let book = text.split("#");

book.forEach((bookText) => {
    let chapter = bookText.split("*");
    chapter.forEach((chapterText, chapterIndex) => {
        let verse = chapterText.split(".");

        volume.push({
            book: "PLACEHOLDER",
            chapters: chapter
                .filter((chapter) => chapter.trim() !== "")
                .map(() => ({
                    chapter: chapterIndex + 1,
                    verses: verse
                        .filter((verse) => verse.trim() !== "")
                        .map((verse, verseIndex) => ({
                            verse: verseIndex + 1,
                            text: verse.trim() + "",
                        })),
                })),
        });
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(volume, null, 2));

Is there a possibility that it is the double map method and or the double forEach method? I tried removing either of them but would give me errors like (bookText.split is not a method and chapterText.split is not a method.)

It is indeed that the cause is double map and foreach, but it's more about how structuring the data and pushing it into the volume array. You pushing a new object into volume for each chapter, which results in duplicating the book information, so you should first create the book object, then add chapters to it, and add verses to each chapter instead:


let text = `
this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 1.
this is book 1, chapter 1, verse 2.
*
this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 1.
this is book 1, chapter 2, verse 2.
#
this is book 2, chapter 1, verse 1.
this is book 2, chapter 1, verse 2.
*
this is book 2, chapter 2, verse 1.
this is book 2, chapter 2, verse 2.
`;

let volume = [];
let books = text.split("#");

books.forEach((bookText) => {
    let book = {
        book: "PLACEHOLDER",
        chapters: []
    };
    let chapters = bookText.split("*");

    chapters.forEach((chapterText, chapterIndex) => {
        let verses = chapterText.split(".");

        book.chapters.push({
            chapter: chapterIndex + 1,
            verses: verses
                .filter((verse) => verse.trim() !== "")
                .map((verse, verseIndex) => ({
                    verse: verseIndex + 1,
                    text: verse.trim() + "",
                })),
        });
    });

    volume.push(book);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(volume, null, 2));




Fixed the issue: I declared the variables like book, chapter, and verse as objects and pushed them into those objects with 1 more forEach() method.
